# resolve .onion address from bash

Tags: onion-services, socks

I have tried using curl through tor like so

```
 curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9050 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.onion
```

This works for public addresses like stackoverflow.com but not for tor .onion addresses

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use `--socks5-hostname` instead of just `--socks5`.

This way, the socks5 proxy does the hostname resolution. Otherwise curl tries to resolve the hostname itself, which it can't.

Answer (score 7):

Moreover, you should use `torsocks` - built-in utility for working with Tor Network.

**It is designed to prevent any leakage!** Please, read the man page.

For example:

```
root@localhost:/# torsocks curl XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.onion
```

Otherwise, if you are trying to resolve .onion name to IPv6, you are able to use `tor-resolve` utility, it is built-in too:

Syntax:

```
root@localhost:/# tor-resolve kpvz7ki2v5agwt35.onion 
fe80:7cd1:5f4e:a9d5:dfe:1976:5edf:4386
```

Of-course, this IP address it temporary one and can be used only from your `localhost` for the limited time.

Moreover, your traffic shall be redirected through Tor's transparent proxy connections port - `TransPort`, which is always, by default `9040`. See the documentation about transparent & isolated proxies on the torproject.org's [wiki](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/IsolatingProxy) site.

Thereafter, you can use this IP directly with `curl`:

```
anonymous@localhost:/$ curl fe80:7cd1:5f4e:a9d5:dfe:1976:5edf:4386
```

Or just use .onion domain:

```
anonymous@localhost:/$ curl XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.onion
```